# Get all specific product types

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get specific product types from the database.

I know how to get all products but I need to filter by just a specific product type.

What I get to till now:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'
```

But where is the product type field?

Comment: Am I missing something? How can anyone answer this without knowing your schema? More importantly you yourself don't know the schema of the database you are querying?

Comment: for product type you need to write join query with meta table

Comment: @Sohaib the schema is well known for WP & Woocommerce

Comment: @MujeebuRahman can you show an example, i'm trying to query product type "simple"

Comment: WP query is fine for you?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman yes i think

Comment: @AhmedNabil Please try my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'product',
       'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'simple', 
            ),
        ),
     );
$products = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($products);
```

Try this